# Checksum for price changes

Tags: language-agnostic, computer-science, checksum

I sync weekly updated product prices with an external data source and then save only the price changes with the valid-from date in a SQL database. In this way, I can later determine the valid price on a given date and save database memory.

Now I would like to integrate a checksum so that I can determine whether the weekly price sync has failed in the past. Is there a checksum algorithm that I can use to specifically check whether a price has been updated in week X without generating so much data that I end up better saving the weekly price, even if it hasn't changed?

Background:
I receive delayed booking data (invoice date, product price on invoice date, quantity) from other external sources and want to validate whether the external source has selected the price correctly using my own price list. This is often not the case.
To make my system more error-resistant, I need to ensure that failed price synchronizations are recognised.

Of course, the safest way would be to save the price again every week, but I would like to save storage space because there are a lot of products involved.

One simple idea would it be to use check bits for each week since the last price update week. 52 bits per year = 7 byte instead of 52 times the full price table row size + indexes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is. It is also not clear how a checksum can be used to determine if a sync failed. Please [edit] your question to include a much more detailed description of the problem you have and one specific question you want to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the scheme you propose- why not just include an `end_week` column on that table. I assume your table already has a `start_week` column, along with the actual price and quantity data. This would enable you to perform queries against historical data a bit easier (`start_week <= week AND week <= end_week`). The data type for this column could be a byte or two in size, depending on how you treat rolling over between years.

Comment: This would also be an option, but weekly updates must not fail either. Otherwise the end_week will be updated again with the next update and you will no longer be able to tell whether the weeks between start_week and end_week are complete.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a checksum to check for price changes without saving the entire price history. Here's how:

Calculate a hash for each week's price data.
Store the hash value along with the week number.
During subsequent price syncs, calculate the hash value again.
Compare the new hash value to the stored hash value.
If the hash values match, the price data hasn't changed.
If the hash values differ, the price data has changed.
This way, you can quickly identify price changes without storing the entire price history.

Comment: `If the hash values match, the price data hasn't changed` - while the opposite is true, this assertion may not actually hold.

Comment: This would ensure that the previous week was synchronised correctly and you would have to intervene immediately if this was not the case. I had hoped that there would be an algorithm that could specifically check week X. You could of course add up all 52 weekly prices and then determine whether a price change is missing somewhere by comparing the total with verified price data, but you wouldn't know in which week or weeks the synchronisation failed.